# How to make an arbirtary number of windows using Python and Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, window, tkinter

I'm writing an app that doesn't have a main window (it runs inside a Python interpreter in another app), and I thought I had a good solution for getting Tkinter to cooperate--I made the `Tkinter.Tk` class into a [Borg](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/).

```
class RootWindow(Tk):
    """ Invisible window that serves as the default parent
        of all others.
    """

    groupDict = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.groupDict
        if self.__dict__ == {}: # first instance
            Tk.__init__(self)
            self.withdraw()
```

Then I have my `Window`s, which are subclassed from `Tkinter.Toplevel`, default to `parent=RootWindow()`. The result should be that I can create any number of `Window`s and they'll use the same root.

It works once fine for the first `Window`, but after that things get all messed up. :(

[see pic](http://img21.imageshack.us/i/failwindow.png)

What am I doing wrong? Is this even a feasible solution?

Thanks

EDIT: I should add that even though there's other stuff running in the picture, the problem can be duplicated just by using `RootWindow` as the parent of a `Tkinter.Toplevel`.

EDIT: I overrode `Window.mainloop` so everything uses the `RootWindow` event loop.

```
def mainloop(self):
    self.master.wait_window(self)
```

Then I create each visible window like this:

`test = Window()
test.mainloop()`

It seems to work because the windows do show up, but their contents are packed in an odd way that's hard to describe. It alternates between no contents at all and having everything squished horizontally and expanded vertically.

Comment: Are you calling mainloop() once for each toplevel window? If so, stop doing that. You must have only a single mainloop() running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem appears to be that you are forgetting to start the event loop. Or, based on further edits of your question, you may be starting more than one main loop.  You need exactly one main loop that is run from the root window.

Tkinter certainly allows an arbitrary number of top level windows, but your question doesn't appear to have enough details to show what is wrong unless my first guess is correct.